# Is it possible to have permissions based on relations?

Tags: php, yii, authorization

The permissions system in Yii--as I understand it--is like different roles in content management systems: a particular role (E.G. moderator, author, admin, etc) can either do a particular operation, or not.

What I want, however, is different. I want users to be able to set whether someone with a particular relationship to them can do a particular operation. For example, a user should be able to say that only his friends can see his profile, or a business can say that only a specific employee of that business (for example, with the user id of 4) can add products.

Is this possible using Yii's authorization system, or do I need to implement my own system?

And also, as a side question, does what I want have a name so that the next time I wouldn't write four lines explaining it? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want does indeed have a name. It's called [business rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#using-business-rules). In your case you could create a RBAC task or operation like `viewFriend` and associate it with a business rule. In that rule you would check, if the current visitor is a friend of the user whose profile you want to show.

You'd check for this permission in the profile's view action. For the permission check you can pass parameters to this rule. In your case this would probably be the user id of the profile you want to view.

Comment: This answers my question, but I'm still not sure whether RBAC is the right approach: I can't use roles and tasks, because it's only the operations I care about, and there is no way of mass-assigning operations to users. For example, I can't just assign the "Friend" role to someone and always say that the friend role can, say, view a profile. For a profile, a friend can view it, whereas in another one, the owner might not allow the user to do such a thing.

Comment: Actually you *can* assign operations to users. Yii's RBAC does not really differ wether you assign a role, a task or an operation to a user. So if you want a very flat RBAC hierarchy with only operations, that's also fine.